# Need help creating a powershell script to update microsoft edge in Azure WVD enviroment (VM's )

Tags: powershell, azure, sccm

> OS : Windows 2019 Server

Requirement steps:

1 - close all sessions in the WVD VM.

2 - launch Edge and open the About page

3 - close edge after a couple of mins and then update it

4. a lot of time through the edge browser is just pending a restart to finish installing it. So is there a way to also force it to check for an update to be included in the script.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Microsoft Edge automatically updates when you restart your browser.
What have you tried yourself so far?

Check the WVDAdmin tool, this tool allows you stop the VM and run scripts.